# Adding a jquery active state to an accordian

Tags: jquery

for the life of me I can not figure out how to add an acitve state to this accordian I have. I feel like im close, but I have to click the bars twice so that the arrow states change. Any ideas on what Im doing wrong?

```
    $('ul.expand').each(function(){
    $('li.md', this).filter(':first').addClass('top').end().filter(':not(.open)').next().hide();
    $('li.md', this).click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('open')) {
            $(this).find('.arrow').addClass('active');
            return false;
        } else {
            $(this).find('.arrow').removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent().find('li.md').removeClass('open').next().filter(':visible').slideUp();
            $(this).addClass('open').next().slideDown();
            $(this).find('.arrow').addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

and here is the HTML:

http://www.lastyearsloss.com/mav/mobile/

Comment: From looking at your code, I would say that quite a few optimizations could be done on it.

Comment: The javascript in your link is not the same as the one you posted here :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the else remove all active classes because the accordion only allows 1 active member.

```
$('li.md').find('.arrow').removeClass('active'); // remove all actives
$(this).find('.arrow').addClass('active');    // activate current
```

Comment: Cool, that fixed the first problem :) thank you. But I still have to click the header twice for the arrow to change.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li.md').find('.arrow.active').removeClass('active');
```

Have you tried that?

Comment: Yeah. It seems I have to click the header bar twice for the arrow to change.